# wp cron repeatedly adding woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async to itself

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron

Any ideas how this can happen

```
a:67:{i:1507619899;a:6:{s:24:"update_wpml_config_index";a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:5:"daily";s:4:"args";a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:86400;}}s:41:"wpseo-premium-prominent-words-recalculate";a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:5:"daily";s:4:"args";a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:86400;}}s:10:"daily_cron";a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:9:"every_day";s:4:"args";a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:86400;}}s:16:"wp_version_check";a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:10:"twicedaily";s:4:"args";a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:43200;}}s:17:"wp_update_plugins";a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:10:"twicedaily";s:4:"args";a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:43200;}}s:16:"wp_update_themes";a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:10:"twicedaily";s:4:"args";a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:43200;}}}i:1507619922;a:3:{s:15:"ao_cachechecker";a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:5:"daily";s:4:"args";a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:86400;}}s:19:"wpseo-reindex-links";a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:5:"daily";s:4:"args";a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:86400;}}s:19:"wp_scheduled_delete";a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:5:"daily";s:4:"args";a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:86400;}}}i:1507619931;a:1:{s:16:"wpm_update_stats";a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:6:"hourly";s:4:"args";a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:3600;}}}i:1507623959;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"f612dd6ba48ac10ee488cd588778f8e8";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34912;}}}}i:1507624725;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"7ddceaed80a666931251c1be50dda1cf";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34913;}}}}i:1507626259;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"1f6718f9bbf0a7712dd235d5bcbda472";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34914;}}}}i:1507626892;a:1:{s:25:"delete_version_transients";a:1:{s:32:"efb4ee09fa8955bbc9d0955e78cc0433";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:1:{i:0;s:10:"1507580385";}}}}i:1507627182;a:1:{s:29:"mc4wp_ecommerce_process_queue";a:1:{s:32:"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a";a:3:{s:8:"schedule";s:13:"every5minutes";s:4:"args";a:0:{}s:8:"interval";i:300;}}}i:1507629928;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"47e1b087ac48b3556437e54827101383";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34915;}}}}i:1507633646;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"2e83432ad8ecf2332a8d73a0c9219ebb";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306565;i:1;i:379094;}}}}i:1507634718;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"643f854f339706691350a82c646d89d1";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34916;}}}}i:1507646323;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"6995df78e702f825813660fa181970cc";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34917;}}}}i:1507646393;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"df94f81f9f31d9fbb96f91b6b2d941fc";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306562;i:1;i:34917;}}}}i:1507646397;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"b19f64eff3769183a206132125c193eb";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306564;i:1;i:381153;}}}}i:1507646427;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"23fd76f1111d20a4cc11bbcb7c975668";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306565;i:1;i:381153;}}}}i:1507655818;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"0675713e377514b3c689e44d541ce965";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34918;}}}}i:1507658778;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"fea188b9f49977933f4ccefd602246fa";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34919;}}}}i:1507662083;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"61263516a3f01081b957a16dcdc84940";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34920;}}}}i:1507662436;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"6719ea827154b4beb88bc0b56ff405ef";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34921;}}}}i:1507665640;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"5b3c252548e9ce1a3b81b5e97ea3a1f8";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306562;i:1;i:19649;}}}}i:1507665645;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"440d62a71bfbaa917cc1815aefac3fa4";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306564;i:1;i:381166;}}}}i:1507665714;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"0b765c8479a6340a8c9b4334de3f2ab7";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306565;i:1;i:381166;}}}}i:1507671085;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"a88a420c38ef2c25df7a125092f94a41";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34922;}}}}i:1507671126;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"5997cb1f889e8faefb1ea665d5b57ced";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306562;i:1;i:34922;}}}}i:1507671130;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"6104f006ff556a6d4a3073ab0a339b96";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306564;i:1;i:381171;}}}}i:1507671295;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"c36d1e517fa8c1b3ec748904eba3f14c";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306565;i:1;i:381171;}}}}i:1507671865;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"577b6f2397fb844fc09e17e40dbe3773";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34923;}}}}i:1507672347;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"abceaa59857ffd3ea7cbbcc861f6c6f1";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34924;}}}}i:1507674778;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"a05c178c1734d83c74960121b94a45ea";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34925;}}}}i:1507677353;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"11bb1503d2b1ae449e8a6c1712fa1bc8";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34926;}}}}i:1507698424;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"c862cf3708db24a6603eac7951de47d0";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34927;}}}}i:1507699031;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"51c9cbebcef739b126de5286d6cb7fdd";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34928;}}}}i:1507704489;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"a62243a4b57573681c10302648c6ccd7";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34929;}}}}i:1507704634;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"55a75ee6c9bcbd5ddc6b6ec59323e7eb";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306562;i:1;i:34929;}}}}i:1507709422;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"fd25e38595ba5cc82aa6b8ff11b70ceb";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34930;}}}}i:1507709566;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"52a9814d45a45134dd6c62373d206646";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306562;i:1;i:34930;}}}}i:1507711557;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"5a5e8468d6970cb2be27384ebf74c1f3";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34931;}}}}i:1507712675;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"3d72903b2265feced0c4757877b06c89";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34932;}}}}i:1507712730;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"70e1b35aa4e5a41c300a55f391a5245f";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306562;i:1;i:34932;}}}}i:1507712735;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"e1be15511cbecdca32d2c081a099174f";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306564;i:1;i:381197;}}}}i:1507712863;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"928ffb6beccc8b8a06db632ae9453733";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306565;i:1;i:381197;}}}}i:1507714615;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"2359f93748d066159291a4133f11d438";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34933;}}}}i:1507714688;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"91488ae3d607beca35260fbe1df36a34";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306562;i:1;i:34933;}}}}i:1507714692;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"5066293cfb88fec4134e41184d7fb874";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306564;i:1;i:381200;}}}}i:1507714713;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"af0408dbd49f260a1a2bf10de86769eb";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306565;i:1;i:381200;}}}}i:1507717982;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"e0bd90350e00b965a1c1b342254f0cf5";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34934;}}}}i:1507729822;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"92f99564f04835cce9f25e3e3eb72b1d";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34935;}}}}i:1507729895;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"4b8f8225e0107ead39e2ea52b2cc1f2f";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306562;i:1;i:34935;}}}}i:1507733772;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"f6b85f3a4d2f5f6c36c57527df2dd341";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34936;}}}}i:1507736995;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"c688d5da0ef4ae8fed55795b69a3cc91";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34937;}}}}i:1507737149;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"6950288361babad669a2ecb1cfee3e99";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306562;i:1;i:34937;}}}}i:1507737154;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"09062c83cb2b2fb21d9eef595d7f6632";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306564;i:1;i:381214;}}}}i:1507737203;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"b43e75000af7a25cba85a00a8c95d068";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306565;i:1;i:381214;}}}}i:1507737592;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"43fd241a5955a6428930389141528c3e";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34938;}}}}i:1507737704;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"20c77430c5f12ae6d23ee81f4e47aa54";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306562;i:1;i:34938;}}}}i:1507737709;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"5a97dda073e8ff2c34b7812c9fcf08aa";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306564;i:1;i:381217;}}}}i:1507737748;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"24b2dafbd8211cb159926a4f31140bc7";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306565;i:1;i:381217;}}}}i:1507743906;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"7500f4d8c83bbf17e0dd20fef815658e";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34939;}}}}i:1507744519;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"d1b81f9085b40f5eefb6bfeacfedf35a";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34940;}}}}i:1507747839;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"cc7bfcad4f3b0e37fbaf890c44e48a1a";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34941;}}}}i:1507795539;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"37692201ec22845c7cc96eb35f041c53";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34942;}}}}i:1507798298;a:1:{s:25:"delete_version_transients";a:1:{s:32:"e62a84fe27d926086c21fa13299ca5ac";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:1:{i:0;s:10:"1507640673";}}}}i:1507814509;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"52a9814d45a45134dd6c62373d206646";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306562;i:1;i:34930;}}}}i:1507814513;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"4a682e4d68df2e74f38932310da7f6e0";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306564;i:1;i:381262;}}}}i:1507814578;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"35bcf437b8366ee8ad604a8b26b4b724";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306565;i:1;i:381262;}}}}i:1507821780;a:1:{s:33:"woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async";a:1:{s:32:"5aac09e679cb036adc0b131084af34ec";a:2:{s:8:"schedule";b:0;s:4:"args";a:2:{i:0;i:306561;i:1;i:34943;}}}}s:7:"version";i:2;}
```

This is the cron job from wp_options after one day, the first time I found it there where around 1400 scheduled tasks in there.

I found the function that is creating the task but it does not help in finding out what is calling it.

```
    if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_webhook_deliver_async', true, $this, $arg ) ) {

        // deliver in background
        wp_schedule_single_event( time(), 'woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async', array( $this->id, $arg ) );

    }
```

Should I just set the filter to false to block it, does it do anything useful?

```
    add_filters( 'woocommerce_webhook_deliver_async', false, 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

use the hook

```
// remove the action 
remove_action( 'woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async', 'action_woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async', 10, 3 );
```

documentation: http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async/